# Issues with website page with video not responsive

Tags: html, css

I had this website and it works but if i make it resize, the logo and the button in the bottom goes awry and all responsiveness is lost, how can i fix it

please guide, here is the url:

[prolexmedia.ca](http://prolexmedia.ca)

My code usage has been like this

```css
.container {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%; 
}
.container video {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:6%;
  z-index:1;
}
.box {
  position:relative;
}
.bet_time {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:6%;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #dbdbdb;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: solid #dbdbdb 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Prolex Media</title>
</head>
<body >
<div class="container">
  <video autoplay id="videos" width="100%" height="100%" muted>
    <source src="live/ProlexCommercial.webm" type='video/webm'/>
  </video>
    <div class="overlay">
        <p><img src="images/logoservices.jpg"/></p>
    </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="bet_time"><a class="btn" href="home.cfm">Skip</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I am not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

try code in css remove css attribute from html

```
video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.overlay {
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.overlay img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100px;
}
.btn {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container{ padding:0;}
```

Comment: Could you please explain little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is in your media query(that you haven't shared here) `.container` has `padding` as below

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

That causes the issue.

1. Here you are suppose to set `padding: 0` to your `.container`
2. Or you are suppose align `.overlay` and `.bet_time` accordingly. Set `.overlay` `left: 15px` and `.bet_time` `right: 15px` if you want `padding` on `.container`.